# zlib - inflate only work after calling inflateinit twice

Tags: exception, zlib, init, compression, inflate

I have some pre-compressed data (compressed with the help of zlib-flate on Linux) inside my RAM. To use this compressed data I want to umcompress it using zlib an inflate.

I have no dynamic memory management on this system but provided a big enough buffer for the uncompressed data. The problem is if I call the inflate routine after calling the inflateInit routine I get an unhandled exception.

But if I call the inflateInit function two times the following inflate (=decompressing) works fine and I get the correct decompressed data into my provided buffer. This is strange isn't it?

I can also do a compression at any time before calling the inflate and it will also work .. what the hell?

Let me show you the behaviour:

1. initInflate
2. inflate > **fail**

new run..

1. initInflate
2. initInflate
3. inflate > **success**

new run..

1. initDeflate
2. deflate (success but I don't use the result)
3. initInflate
4. inflate > **success**

There is an array somewhere holding the compressed data:

```
uint8_t src [] = {.....};
```

This is my buffer which is definetly big enough to contain the complete decompressed data.

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1000
uint8_t buf[BUF_SIZE];
```

And this is the code of my decompressing:

```
z_stream strm;

strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree  = Z_NULL;
strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
strm.avail_in = srcLen;
strm.next_in = src;
strm.avail_out = BUF_SIZE;
strm.next_out = buf;
strm.data_type = Z_BINARY;

inflateInit(&strm);
inflateInit(&strm); // the follwing inflate only works with this second init

inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
```

I can see that the `state` member of the stream is changing from `0x40193678` after the first init to `0x40195250` after the second init (maybe this is a important info for you). And both inits are response with `Z_OK`.

And now I hope you can help me..

Comment: What exactly does "fail" and "success" mean here? What is `inflate()` returning?

Comment: If the 'inflate()' was sucessful `Z_STREAM_END` is returned. If the inflate failes (e.g. because I only called the `inflateInit()` once) it seems that I run into an **unhandled exception** because my program counter jumps to nowhere (boot vector or something similar - the program chrashes).

Comment: What do you mean by "I have no dynamic memory management on this system"?

Comment: There is no `malloc` function implemented in my program. Therefore I provided a big enough buffer (I know the size of the uncompressed data) so that the zlib can process the complete data in one single run..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it's doing is allocating memory for the stream twice, using only the second allocation. I can only guess that you are overwriting just the memory allocated by the first `inflateInit()`, due to some other error in your program. The overwriting crashes `inflate()` when it is trying to use the first allocation, but succeeds on when using the second allocation, which is not overwritten by the other bug.

Comment: Maybe you can help me to understand the behaviour a bit better. Will the library always allocate memory (with it's internal standard functions if zalloc, zfree and opaque set to Z_ZERO) even if I already provided a buffer which is big enough? Or does the library need other temporary buffers (for internal purposes besides the raw result/destination buffer? Nevertheless thank you for your support!

Comment: I could figure out that inside of `inflate_fast()` function at [line 114](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/inffast.c#L114) the variable `bits` becomes a **strange** value of `0xFFFFFF2` which seems to be the result of `bits - op` whre `op` is greater than `bits`. And that causes the faulty pointer value written into `strm->next_in` at [line 299](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/inffast.c#L299). :-(

Comment: Regardless of the output buffer you give it, `inflateInit()` will always allocate memory for its own use, using `malloc()` if you give `Z_NULL`s. Later `inflateEnd()` will use `free()` to release the memory.

Comment: It seems the problem was caused by multi-threading. I could fix the described problem by adding a critical section.